# How to to get Image file metadata from it's path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, speed-test

I want to upload a image file from `Reactjs` which is in my project folder (`"../assets.cover.png"`) without using input, when I'm trying  `import cover from "../assets.cover.png"` it's giving me file path but what I need is file metadata to upload it.

Basically my final intention is to upload that image file and calculate user upload speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve it after reading after reading this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File)

```js
import cover from "../assets/cover.png"; // importing img file

let blob = await fetch(cover).then((r) => r.blob()); //creating blob object

const file = new File([blob], "cover.png", {
  type: "image/png",
});

console.log(file);

// output
// {
//   lastModified: 1656486792733
//   lastModifiedDate: Wed Jun 29 2022 12:43:12 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {}
//   name: "cover.png"
//   size: 1446458
//   type: "image/png"
//   webkitRelativePath: ""
// }
```

Answer (score 0):

The imported image is just a file path relative to the base url for use on properties, you'll have to read the file to do what you are attempting.

Comment: How to read image file and get it's baseUrl ? @RuiSiang

Comment: In your case, the "cover" variable that you got from the import statement is the image files url relative to the react app baseurl.

Comment: Is there is any way to get metadata of file just like we get when we use input of type files for eg 
`coverImg: File
lastModified: 1655965886803
lastModifiedDate: Thu Jun 23 2022 12:01:26 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {}
name: "1655921371215_eventCover.avif"
size: 35518
type: "image/avif"
webkitRelativePath: ""
[[Prototype]]: File
[[Prototype]]: Object
`

@RuiSiang